# React-Native run-android app crashes immediately

Tags: android, react-native

I am pretty new to react native and try to run an app with `react-native run-android` so without expo. 
The app installs successfully but it crashes immediately without errors.
I've created the app with `react-native init myapp`

When I try to run an app with Android Studio everything works fine. Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: Try upgrading react-native: `react-native upgrade` and then `react-native run-android`.

Comment: Didn't work but I just let it run on an emulator now. On the phone it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was missing the permission to draw it over other apps.

**Settings -> Applications -> [Select App] -> Permissions -> Flow over Screen -> Allow**

Comment: this is moved from permissions to the bottom of the "select app" step

Answer (score 28):

`./gradlew clean` fixed the crash for me

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget to restart your bundler: `npm start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how relevant this answer is but still I'll answer this. In my case the app was crashing immediately, but there was some error on the screen (it was not being logged in the console though). It was quickly closing so I was unable to see the error. After some time I found out that I was passing the `size` prop's value as `medium` in the `ActivityIndicator`. That's why it was crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my laptop did it for me.

I have no idea what the underlying issue is.
I'm on mac OS Big sur (11.6.5), I use hermes and flipper.

Answer (score 0):

If you running app on `emulator` try running on `device` , when i run it on device it worked.

then reload app after running on device.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was RAM problem, that was causing app crash

`I was running my App with phone that had 2GB RAM,`
`On testing it in 8GB device it worked perfectly`

If you are doing `intensive tasks` with your app like like `video processing, compression or conversion etc.`

RAM could create issue so please do check this scenario also